# how to Run vba program automatically

Tags: vb.net

I have a outlook vba code for mail attachments download.
I want it to be executed automatically at 10 pm daily.
How to achieve this? I have tried different approaches.

Comment: try execute externally by task scheduler ..

Comment: Matzone, since this is an asnwer, you could have put it as an Answer rather than a comment